# Marker Info-window not working using ngMap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, google-maps-markers, ng-map

I am trying to show an info window on google map using [ng-map](/questions/tagged/ng-map). Here's my code:

```
<div id="map">
  <ng-map zoom="13" center="[{{latitude}}, {{longitude}}]" style="display: block; height: 100%;">
    <marker ng-repeat="pothole in potholeData" position="{{pothole.lat}},{{pothole.lng}}" on-click="showDetails(e, pothole)"></marker>
  </ng-map>
</div>
```

I am giving an `on-click` function on each marker with a lat and long value. but in my controller I am getting `undefined` value.

Here's my controller:

```
$scope.showDetails = function(e, pothole) {
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var center = new google.maps.LatLng(pothole.lat, pothole.lng);

  infowindow.setContent(
    '<h3>' + pothole + '</h3>');

  infowindow.setPosition(center);
  infowindow.open($scope.map);
}
```

In `showDetails` function, I am getting `pothole` `undefined`.
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in `on-click="showDetails(e, pothole)`, change to `on-click="showDetails(event, pothole)`.
I have produced snippet working.

```js
angular.module('mapApp', ['ngMap'])
    .controller('mapController', function($scope, NgMap) {

        NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
            $scope.map = map;
        });
        $scope.potholeData = [
            { lat: 59.923043, lng: 10.752839 },
            { lat: 59.339025, lng: 18.065818 },
            { lat: 55.675507, lng: 12.574227 },
            { lat: 52.521248, lng: 13.399038 },
            { lat: 48.856127, lng: 2.346525 }
        ];
        $scope.showDetails = function(e, pothole) {
          console.log(pothole);
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          var center = new google.maps.LatLng(pothole.lat,pothole.lng);

          infowindow.setContent(
            '<h3>' + pothole.lat + " " + pothole.lng + '</h3>');

          infowindow.setPosition(center);
          infowindow.open($scope.map);
        };

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapController">
    <ng-map default-style="true" zoom="5" center="59.339025, 18.065818">
        <marker ng-repeat="pothole in potholeData"
                position="{{pothole.lat}},{{pothole.lng}}" on-click="showDetails(event, pothole)">
        </marker>
    </ng-map>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I have the exact same code. I have included all the scripts. I am not where I went wrong

Comment: @chan You need change `on-click="showDetails(e, pothole)` to `on-click="showDetails(event, pothole)`. See the `event` parameter. That was the real issue.

Comment: @artgb Thanks for the answer. I just have one question. How can I add style to that info window?

Answer (score 1):

According to @artgb answer you need change `on-click="showDetails(e, pothole)` to `on-click="showDetails(event, pothole)`. See the `event` parameter. That was the real issue.

In this full [ng-map](/questions/tagged/ng-map)version works the same way.

According to https://ngmap.github.io/.

1. You need these scripts:

   1. `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCGsmJhDsK9HS2_kYtQXbiJqaAE2AT_Pw0"></script>`. `AIzaSyCGsmJhDsK9HS2_kYtQXbiJqaAE2AT_Pw0` is my API KEY for this demo. You can get your own in: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/.
   2. `<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>`
   3. `<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>`
2. You need to identify your markers with an id. As you are using `ngRepeat` I'm using this data:

---

```
[{
  "id": "Location1",
  "text": "Some content 1...",
  "lat": -12.339223,
  "lng": -76.808624
}, {
  "id": "Location2",
  "text": "Some content 2...",
  "lat": -12.349423,
  "lng": -76.828824
}]
```

---

3. The [ng-map](/questions/tagged/ng-map) directive contains the original Google Maps V3 api to the user so you don't need to use `new google.maps` Object.

Something like this:

```js
(function() {

  angular.module("app", ["ngMap"]).controller("Controller", ["$scope", "NgMap", function($scope, NgMap) {
    NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
      $scope.map = map;
    });

    $scope.latitude = -12.339223;
    $scope.longitude = -76.808624;
    $scope.potholeData = [{
      "id": "Location1",
      "text": "Some content 1...",
      "lat": -12.339223,
      "lng": -76.808624
    }, {
      "id": "Location2",
      "text": "Some content 2...",
      "lat": -12.349423,
      "lng": -76.828824
    }];
    $scope.pothole = {};

    $scope.showDetails = function(e, pothole) {
      $scope.pothole = pothole;
      $scope.map.showInfoWindow('foo-iw', pothole.id);
    };

    $scope.hideDetail = function() {
      $scope.map.hideInfoWindow('foo-iw');
    };
  }]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCGsmJhDsK9HS2_kYtQXbiJqaAE2AT_Pw0"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>

<div data-ng-app="app">
  <div data-ng-controller="Controller">
    <ng-map default-style="true" center="{{latitude}}, {{longitude}}" zoom="13">
      <marker id="{{pothole.id}}" ng-repeat="pothole in potholeData" position="{{pothole.lat}},{{pothole.lng}}" on-click="showDetails(event, pothole)"></marker>

      <info-window id="foo-iw">
        <div ng-non-bindable="">
          id: {{pothole.id}}<br/> Text: {{pothole.text}}<br/> Position: {{anchor.getPosition()}}
        </div>
      </info-window>
    </ng-map>
  </div>
</div>
```